# Why are switching DC/DC regulators so constrained on input voltage? How can I manage drops from higher voltages?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, switching-regulator

I'm looking to generate a stable 5 V and/or 12 V output from a DC input that could be up to 120 V. Inspecting the Farnell range at least, with no filters, the greatest DC input voltage is 75 V. How can a higher drop be achieved?

Why can linear regulators and LDOs drop much higher voltages (albeit inefficiently,) whereas switching regulators cannot?

Comment: Check BigClive's "Dubai lamp" video, using a dropper capacitor to source voltage for the leds, you can also use a voltage divider from than on, linear regulator get pretty hot if the input voltage is to high relative to the output, that's wasted energy.

Comment: You can get 150 volt Buck regulators from Farnell: https://uk.farnell.com/analog-devices/ltc3639hmse-pbf/dc-dc-conv-sync-buck-150deg-c/dp/4033520

Comment: You did not mention a wattage of interest.

Comment: You have not stated a minimum input voltage. Note that most every AC/DC adapter runs happily on DC (input voltage limits may well differ). (You may or may not want to skip the input rectifier.)

Comment: Note that efficient designs with big voltage ratios use different circuits than efficient designs with small voltage ratios. Maybe a 6-300V -> 5V supply exists somewhere, but it won't be nearly as efficient when the input is 300V, than when it's 6V. This is related to duty cycle and I2R losses. Supplies designed for big ratios will avert the problem by using transformers.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking to generate a stable 5 V and/or 12 V output from a DC input that could be up to 120 V.

Sounds like a run off-the-mill supply. You probably have a drawer full of USB supplies – that exactly.

> Inspecting the Farnell range at least, with no filters, the greatest DC input voltage is 75 V. How can a higher drop be achieved?

This might be an issue of "branding", more than technical feasibility.

You can basically step down any voltage you care to handle, but of course, at some point, isolation needs make things large and unwieldy.

Anyways, as said, for 120V, you could probably just use a common switch-mode supply designed for AC – you just omit the rectification needed for the internal DC/DC stage of your consumer and industrial 5V or 12V power supply.

> Why can linear regulators and LDOs drop much higher voltages (albeit inefficiently), whereas switching regulators cannot?

That's definitely *not* the case.

Comment: RE: this might just be branding: Might really just be *categorization*. TME certainly usually has a smaller catalog than farnell, but look at all the [120V DC in](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/katalog/dc-dc-converters_100320/?mapped_params=624%3A1835856%2C1880816%2C1822202%2C1876019%2C1737377%2C1786300%2C1883321%2C1584730%2C1584853%2C1737359%2C1709624%2C1883322%2C1943980%2C1946632%2C1835180%2C1523659%2C1813738%2C1481955%2C1802330%2C1916839%2C1612801%3B) supplies they have.

Comment: Looking at the range of converters, they are all monolithic units that I assume are a conglomerate of various subcomponents. If this is the case, I am still interested in what is the controller/IC that is running the device at that voltage.

Comment: honestly, go to any distributor, go to the DC/DC converter controller IC category. Isolation needs aside, you can basically use any DC/DC controller that uses an external switch transistor with an arbitrary high input voltage; there's nothing about that voltage which the controller gets in contact with; it just needs to drive the transistor (typically: drive the gate driver of a switching MOSFET), and deal with the voltage feedback from the output side.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are switching DC/DC regulators so constrained on input voltage?

Because Switch-Mode Power Supplies (SMPS) are always a trade-off between many variables during design.  Their whole reason for existence is to be more efficient than Linear Low-DropOut (LDO) regulators, and they achieve this through a fundamentally different approach (inductor switching) as opposed to linear dissipation.  This ends up placing a stiff limitation on input voltage range, because the inductor can only switch so much current, so fast, and with so much duty cycle.  Beyond a certain input voltage range, that inductor/switching controller can no longer satisfy timing requirements.

See, if one particular inductor is chosen, it might be operable from 6-48 V input; if a different inductor is chosen, it might only run from 48-120 V input.  To ask one inductor to cover the whole 6-120 V range is impossible - the range is too large and will violate timing constraints at one end or the other, leading to loss of regulation at least (SMPS failure/fire at worst.)

> How can I manage drops from higher voltages?

SMPS are commonly found in the industrial sector with inputs of up to 800 VDC or more.  Higher voltages are not an issue, although these parts and datasheets are not marketed towards consumers so they can seem "hard to find."  However, these higher-voltage supplies also require a minimum of several hundred volts to startup - that's just the nature of SMPS.

The other answer addresses "wide range" (monolithic) commercial options, which may satisfy these requirements.  If these are found to be insufficient, it may be possible to design a dual-range SMPS with *two* input primaries on the same (custom) bobbin - one for a lower voltage range, and one for a higher voltage range.  Such a design would be challenging; can't say I've seen this done, but it should be feasible.  The switching devices would have to all be rated for far beyond the highest voltage, and maybe a relay added to disconnect the precharge circuitry for the lower-voltage regulator.  Plus some way to monitor the incoming voltage level and switch between the two intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can linear regulators and LDOs drop much higher voltages (albeit inefficiently,) whereas switching regulators cannot?

Linear regulators in practice can't either and often have much less usable range since they turn excessive voltage to heat.

More excess voltage = more heat = less current you can draw from it. Since the linear regulator is burning power and P=VI more output current also means more heat is explicitly burned off. So you can only get the highest input voltages if you only need to miniscule output currents

> whereas switching regulators cannot?

Switching regulators have limits on the shortest pulse they produce  in their switching transistor; They can't make their shortest pulse infinitely short. That limits how low an output voltage you can go below the input.

Then their inductor has limited inductance which means there is a limit to how much they can slow a current rise from reaching damaging peak current levels, and this rate of rise increases with input voltage.

> could be up to 120 V

120VAC? Or 120VDC? Because 120VAC is in RMS and actually has peak voltages of 170V. For example, deriving a DC voltage from 120VAC actually gives you 170VDC.

> How can a higher drop be achieved?

Take a look at hysteretic converters.

Comment: 120 V DC that is.

Comment: @JCollins Understood

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, you're looking for "regulators" vs. controllers.  These tend to divide into groups:

Among regulators (read: controller plus switch(es) integrated), you have products meeting typical applications.  These largely cluster around low voltage, automotive and telecom (under 5, up to 52V or so), and offline/mains (say 100 to 400V, and above for industrial applications).  The latter may still operate to low voltages (example: many LinkSwitch parts run down to 30V or so), but may not provide much power (since the current limit is the same, but, well, that's a tiny fraction of nominal voltage).  They may also have large dropout voltages (e.g. a buck that can only go up to 95% duty cycle or something like that).

Controllers (read: external switch only) also cluster similarly, so there is some care needed here.  Those with internal gate drivers, will be limited in voltage range, perhaps 60-120V or 500-700V+ as typical groupings.  The high voltage types similarly may not be suitable for low voltages, or they may have power supply-specific features that aren't desired in a more general or DC-input or wide-range application (e.g. a line filter capacitor discharge circuit; specific startup features, fault conditions, etc.).

Whereas controllers that provide logic (or ground-referenced gate drive) outputs, can be married with bootstrap or isolated gate drivers for arbitrary voltage ranges.  Examples are mostly quite old unfortunately: TL494 for example.  You may require quite a bit of external logic to build up the desired features (UVLO, startup, fault, etc.), and will still be limited by the low frequency and high current consumption of these chips (or the cost of better performing but legacy parts e.g. the more obscure UC3xxx types?).

The main difficulty (regardless of internal/external driver or LV/HV application) is, bootstrap doesn't work well for buck type (the bootstrap doesn't charge in general), leading to a somewhat complicated solution (e.g. isolated HS drive supply).  A synchronous configuration may be preferred for this reason (a forced low-side switch ensures bootstrap charge).

You might even consider an isolated style, to leverage the turns ratio of the transformer -- you aren't required to use a forward or flyback converter across isolated grounds, they can be common too, of course.  The transformer may take up more space, but this may be compensated with a simpler / more conventional controller/regulator.

---

Regarding the application: if this is a wide input converter (sounds similar to a rail application?), there are several options you might consider.

If the high voltage is only momentary (crossed wires, or e.g. automotive load dump transient), and continuous operation is not required, consider a switch to disable or disconnect the supply during the excursion.  The switch is rated for the maximum peak input voltage, and the converter only sees nominal (or zero when switched off) voltage.  Mind that the switch opens quickly enough so that the converter isn't overvoltaged during the rising edge.

If continuous, a preregulator could be used.  This can be tricky: be careful about falling into procedural traps.  That is, I've seen circuits designed with such a thought process before: "`IF` voltage > threshold, `THEN` enable pre-regulator; switch input from direct to pre-regulator".  Well, what's wrong with this you ask?  The problem is time: circuits are continuous, comparators are (very specifically!) discontinuous.  All the while, the [main] converter is drawing load current; if that switchover doesn't happen instantaneously (actually, even if it does!*), its input might drop out, interrupting the load (or doing further weirdness by upsetting the control loop); and conversely when switching off, does it change over without interruption?  Finally, how fast, and often, is this comparison made?  An average analog comparator can toggle millions of times per second; hysteresis must be added to at least ensure the converter(s) own input ripple doesn't cause the switch to chatter.

*Since, the input and pre-reg almost certainly don't have the same voltages in that instant, so a slug of current will dis/charge the converter's input capacitors.  *Rate matters!*

What's the preferred solution?  Continuity: simply make the pre-regulator operate at up to 100% duty cycle.  (This isn't always trivial; again, an NMOS is preferred for a buck switch, which requires duty cycle under 100% to refresh a bootstrap capacitor; a charge pump or auxiliary supply may be required.)  There is no switchover necessary, the pre-regulator is always, er, pre-regulating; it's just that, when input is low, it's doing all it can do, which is to say, saturating to 100% duty, passing input to output with minimal dropout.

Conversely, instead of a buck-type pre-regulator, a boost could be used to cover the low range.  (Another automotive example: operation required during cold cranking, Vin below 8V or so, for a few seconds.)  This needs 0% duty cycle when disabled (Vin > threshold), which is provided passively by a diode, but a diode costs quite a bit of efficiency and a synchronous boost may be preferable, in which case the sync. rect. needs 100% duty -- the same issue as before (NMOS preferred, needs boosted gate voltage).

And again, you might prefer a transformer-coupled method to get more favorable ratios from a single stage.  There are also tapped buck/boost/SEPIC configurations that might be of interest.  And "flying inductor" or buck-boost (same polarity) configurations, including highly integrated offerings like AD/LT µModules.

Generally speaking, there's no good solution to this problem, and the best solution will come down to, trying most of them (at least at a design level: specing components, estimating efficiency, cost and size) and see which one(s) fit the project specs best.